# Select a column based on a condition SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have a situation like this:

```
SELECT 
   fName, 
   lName
FROM employee as e
join payroll as p ON p.frn_employeeid = e.employeeId
```

For employeeId = 2 (WHERE e.employeeId = 2) I also want to add another column on the select clause payCheck

```
 SELECT 
   fName, 
   lName,
   payCheck (this column should show on the report ONLY if employeeId = 2)
FROM employee as e
join payroll as p ON p.frn_employeeid = e.employeeId
```

I appreciate any help on achieving this.

Note:
I know that one thing I can do is use two queries and then check if employeeId =2 run let say query 1 else run query 2 .
I am looking if there is a away to use only one "SMART" query

Answer (score 5):

The Case Statement would give you what you want:

```
SELECT fName, lName,
    CASE
        WHEN e.employeeid = 2
            THEN payCheck
        ELSE
            ''
    END AS Paycheck
FROM employee as e
    JOIN payroll as p ON p.frn_employeeid = e.employeeId
```

To exclude the column entirely, use the IF THEN statements:

```
IF (employeeid = 2)
    SELECT fname, lname, paycheck
    FROM employee as e
        JOIN payroll as p ON p.frn_employeeid = e.employeeId
ELSE
    SELECT fname, lname
    FROM employee as e
        JOIN payroll as p ON p.frn_employeeid = e.employeeId
```

Comment: This query select the column Paycheck in both cases (employeed = 2 and employee <>2). I want that column to be on the table only if employee = 2.

So, for employee = 2, query result will have three columns, for employee <>2 query result will ONLY have two columns.

Comment: It is saying "employeeid" is invalid column name. I event tried with fname, IF(fname = 'john') and it still says fname is an invalid column name while that exact column name is used on the SELECT statement and is not underlined as invalid.
Is my understanding that the column name fname is not defined inside the IF parentheses, since fname is a column on the employee table.

Comment: So, you're not passing in employeeid.  I think you just need to handle this outside of SQL.

Comment: Thank you, I will see how I can get around of this.